# Save Image to IIS Server with XMLHttpRequest and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, iis, xmlhttprequest

I have a web application which allows users to take a picture with a webcam, which is then displayed as an HTML canvas. The canvas is then successfully converted to an image, which is displayed and then sent to the server using an XMLHttpRequest. This process takes place when the following JS function is triggered:

```
function convertCanvasToImage() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let image = new Image();
    document.getElementById("profile").src = canvas.toDataURL();
 
    var newName = canvas.toDataURL();
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'saveimage.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(encodeURI('imgBase64=' + newName));
}
```

The PHP code, saveimage.php, then processes the image to be saved to the server:

```
  define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/new.png');   
  $img = $_POST['imgBase64'];   
  $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);   
  $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);   
  $data = base64_decode($img);   
  $file = UPLOAD_DIR;//. uniqid() . '.png';   
  $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);   
  print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

This process works exactly as intended when on a local server (XAMPP), but when running on IIS (IIS10 on Windows Server 2019) I am getting the 'Unable to save the file.' message.

I am assuming this a security issue with IIS, but am not sure if the solution involves something with PHP headers, something with CORS in IIS, or something else entirely. Any suggestions?

Comment: check directory permison or output result before save

Comment: Thank you, editing directory permission solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Confirmed this was a folder permissions issue

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is solved, please share your answer to help others who have similar problems.